# Dynamicdatadisplay d3 c# draw points separately (dot to dot ) from List

Tags: c#, drawing

I have a question. I want to draw separated points in plotter from List of point. (point to point drawing). I am working with Dymanic Data Display (D3) C#. Actually I drew it, but points are connected to a line, It's not the thing which I want to see. I did it like this:

```
 calculator.CalculateSequence();
 var xCoord = new EnumerableDataSource<double>(calculator.XCoordinates);
 var yCoord = new EnumerableDataSource<double>(calculator.YCoordinates);
 xCoord.SetXMapping(x => x);
 yCoord.SetYMapping(y => y);
 CompositeDataSource plotterPoints = new CompositeDataSource(xCoord, yCoord);
 plotter.AddLineGraph(plotterPoints);
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution of my problem. For pointwise drawing do this

```
plotter.AddLineGraph(p_plotterPoints,
    new Pen(Brushes.White, 0),
    new CirclePointMarker { Size = 2.0, Fill = Brushes.Black },
    new PenDescription("U.S. cities"));
```